# Clouddeploy and iframes

Tags: wolfram-cloud, cloud-deploy, webmathematica, formpage

I am trying to migrate from webMathematica to Mathematica online on my educational website:
https://sameradeeb-new.srv.ualberta.ca

I ran into the following two problems:
1) Having multiple iframes with multiple clouddeploy pages results in some pages not working properly:
https://sameradeeb-new.srv.ualberta.ca/introduction-to-numerical-analysis/finding-roots-of-equations/
A visitor has to refresh multiple times to get some iframes to display properly. Othertimes it seems that the different iframes might be using the same kernel resulting in errors.

2) Clouddeploy created with formpage within an iframe "steals the focus" of the webpage when loaded. 
https://sameradeeb-new.srv.ualberta.ca/introduction-to-numerical-analysis/numerical-differentiation/

Are there solutions to the above problems or is it better to simply provide links rather than use iframes?

thanks
Samer